# how to make date & time inputs dynamic

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, laravel

i've form has 2 inputs date/time but its static i have an idea but don't know if its applicable or not.

i want the 2 inputs have default now();

if the didn't change its value it stored to db with the now(); date and time,

but if he changed it to another date and time the stored value be his choice,

is this can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use laravel helper function

```
now()
```

also you have use carbon class:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()
```

this is an example:

```
  $data = array("name" => $name,"address" => $address,"created_at"=> Carbon::now(),"updated_at"=> now());
DB::table('student')->insert($data);
```